# When do we generally use $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ substitution?

Tags: integration, analysis, soft-question

I was scrolling on the forum and I saw somebody solving the following integral :

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

He used the really smart substitution $x= \frac{1-t}{1+t}$, but I have no idea how he thought about that.

It reminds me slightly the half angle tangent substitution (Weierstrass substitution ?).

So my questions are :

1. Is it a well-known substitution ?
2. When do we usually use it ? Are there indicators ?
3. Can you give me an example where it works well ?

Thank you.

Comment: [When to use $y = \frac{1 + x}{1 - x}$ when evaluating definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131250/when-to-use-y-frac1-x1-x-when-evaluating-definite-integrals) is not an exact duplicate of your question, but it seems that its answers ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131279/78967) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131347/78967)) answer (some of) your questions.

Comment: This substitution is based on the identity $\displaystyle \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)=\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}$

Comment: Related is "*4. Simultaneously Eliminate First-Degree Terms in the Two Quadratic Factors*" and "*5. Applying the Change of Variable* $\;x = \frac{at+b}{t+1}\;$ *to the Integrand*" in my answer to [How to integrate $ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+10x^2-96x-71}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681893/13130)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well-known. Here are some noticeable examples of the substitution $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac1x-1\right)}{1+x}dx
=\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln2}{1+t}dt=\frac12\ln^22\\
\\
&\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^3}dx =\int_0^1\frac{t+1}{3t^2+1}dt=\frac13\left(\ln2+\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\right)\\
\\
&\int_0^{\pi/4}\tanh^{-1}(\tan x)\ dx\overset{\tan x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}}= \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt=\frac12G
\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It is better (or it is, in my opinion at least) to use trigonometry here. If we let $x=\tan \theta$, then if $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\log(1+x) dx$ then $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log (1+\tan \theta)  d\theta$.

Thus (if $u=\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta$), then $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log (1+\frac{1-\tan u}{1+\tan u})  du$. Hence $I=\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2-\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log (1+\tan u)  du$. So $I=-I+\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2$.

I think this question is from the STEP math exam.